# Collection not loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

These are my classes

```
public class Foo
{
    //private ICollection<Bar> _bars; tried both ways with commented and uncommented fragments

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
        //get { return _bars ?? (_bars = new List<Bar>()); }
        //protected set { _bars = value; }


    public DateTime CreatedOnUtc { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Foo")]
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}

// in my DbContext I have
DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
```

When I load set of elements with

```
    public IQueryable<Core.Domain.Foo.Foo> GetFoos(bool include)
    {
        return include ? _fooRepository.Table.Include(x => x.Bars).AsTracking() : _fooRepository.Table;
    }
```

`Bar` entities are loaded. But when I try to load single entity `_fooRepository.Table.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == fooId)` I can't get the `Bar` collection loaded, it's always empty or null depending on what is commented or uncommented in `Foo` class definition.

How to get this working?

Comment: `_fooRepository.Table.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == fooId)`. You are missing the `.Include` statement here. EFCore 1.0 and 1.1 doesn't support lazy loading yet, so you **always** have to explicitly load it

Comment: oh well, that sucks. thanks

Comment: `.Include()` isn't explicit loading, it uses eager loading, as explained here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application